# Running 3.1.x iPhone Simulator after upgrading to 3.2.4

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I have an app that I want to distribute to 3.1.x devices, but I don't have a device to test on. I ran the app on another dev's 3.1 device, and it crashes, so I definitely have some debugging to do. Rather than find and buy an old 3.x device, I'd like to run a 3.1.x Simulator.

Is there any way to do that?

I have upgraded my XCode install to 3.2.4, and now I no longer have the old XCode installs. It seems that the solution is to have both the new developer package AND the old package installed side-by-side. But I can't find where to download the old package, and the proper install procedure, or if there's another way to test on 3.1.x.

Comment: This thread seems to imply the answer is "that's not supported, don't do that." Which is nice, but ... can I still get the old SDK somewhere? https://devforums.apple.com/message/244347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the links floating around the net don't seem to work anymore.

Cocoa with Love still has the best explanation, but its links are dead:
http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html

This page has an updated set of links.
http://peter.boctor.net/2010/06/24/older-versions-of-xcode-iphone-sdk/

Comment: Thanks, those are working links! Due to time constraints I wound up buying a 3.1.3 device, but knowing where to get the old versions of the SDK is still useful.